# Bounded sequence in dual space applied to sequences in $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

I am not sure how to approch this question.

$c_0$ is the space of sequences converging to zero, with the endowed norm being supreme of $|y_n|$ for $y_n$ in the sequence y. $j$ is an isomorphism between $c_0$ and $X_0$, a closed subspace of a seperable Banach space $X$.

Prove that there exists a bounded sequence $x^*_n$ in $X_0$ such that for all $y$ in $c_0$ $<j(y),x^*_n>=y_n$ for all natural number n.

---

My idea: I kind of find this question trivial.

I consider the linear map from $c_0$ to $X_0$, say, $T_n$ where $T_n(y)=y_n$.

Then $|T_n(j(y))|<=|y_n|<=||j(y)||$, since $|y_n|$ is less than or euqal to the norm of y (supreme of y_n in the sequence), and unitary mapping preserves norm so we have |T(j((y))|<= ||j(y)||.

That makes T a bounded linear transformation for all elements in $X_0$. Then I just let $<x^*_n,u>=T_n(u)$ for u in $X_0$ and zero otherwise. $x^*_n$ is an element of $X^*$ obviously. Then the sequence is found.

However I think this is unlikely the solution. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can't extend $T_n$ as you did, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645421/why-do-we-need-the-hahn-banach-theorem-to-extend-a-bounded-linear-functional). But try using Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135210/question-about-hahn-banach-theorem).